# Помогите с решением задачи. Циклы

Tags: python, input, while

Доброй ночи.
Второй день пытаюсь решить поставленную задачу. Сам я новичок, практикуюсь ежедневно по несколько часов, но случилась какая-то напасть, не могу решить и все. Не сплю практически, все думаю над решением.
Прошу сердечно помочь, растолкуйте пожалуйста, я в тупике.

Задача:
Посчитайте произведение всех чисел последовательности, заканчивающейся нулем. Если чисел в последовательности нет – выведите нейтральное для произведения число – 1.

Ввод:

Последовательность чисел, каждое в новой строке

Вывод:

res – произведение всех чисел

Sample Input: 1 2 -1 0
Sample Output: -2

```
tasks = [1]
n = int(input())
while n:
    tasks.append(n)
    n = int(input())
if len(tasks) == 1:
    print(*tasks)
else:
    del tasks[0]
    print(abs(int(*tasks[:1])) - abs(int(*tasks[1:(len(tasks))-1])) - abs(int(*tasks[(len(tasks))-1:(len(tasks))])))
```

Неверное решение #806248107
Python 3.10
Failed test #2 of 3. Runtime error

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/sandbox/main.py", line 10, in 
print(abs(int(*tasks[:1])) - abs(int(*tasks[1:(len(tasks))-1])) - abs(int(*tasks[(len(tasks))-1:(len(tasks))])))
TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (5 given)

Comment: Если вам нужно произведение чисел, то зачем эта часть кода `print(abs(int(*tasks[:1])) - abs(int(*tasks[1:(len(tasks))-1])) - abs(int(*tasks[(len(tasks))-1:(len(tasks))])))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот обычное умножение.

Так и не понял, что вы пытались написать эти `print(abs(int(*tasks[:1])) - abs(int(*tasks[1:(len(tasks))-1])) - abs(int(*tasks[(len(tasks))-1:(len(tasks))])))`

```
numbers = []

while n := int(input('num: ')):
    numbers.append(n)

nul = 1
print('mul: ', -1 if len(numbers) == 0 else [nul := nul * n for n in numbers][-1])
```

Comment: `if n == 0: break` - избыточно, поскольку по `while 0` уже происходит выход из цикла

Comment: да, можно убрать

Answer (score 1):

Список здесь не нужен, поскольку он усложняет вычисления и не выводится как результат - достаточно одной переменной для формирования произведения.
Если чисел в последовательности нет, то выводится `1` как [нейтральное число](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82) для произведения, то есть то число, которое не меняет произведение.

```
m = 1
while True:
    x = int(input('Число: '))
    if x:
        m *= x
    else:
        break

print(f'Произведение:{m}')
```

```
Число: 1
Число: 2
Число: -1
Число: 0
Произведение:-2
```

Comment: @MBo  Учел. Это не минус 1, а дефис 1. Нейтральное число - это 1.

Comment: Во как, оказывается ;)